# Machine-learning using an aggregation function

Tags: machine-learning, python, aggregation

I am looking for a machine-learning algorithm (ANN, random forest,...) that is able to account for an aggregation function during the learning step.

I want to estimate variable Y from variables X1,X2,...Xn:

Y = f(X1,X2,...Xn)

I have observations of:

- X1,X2,...Xn for each sample (approx. 50k)
- Y for each group of samples (approx. 10k)
- Aggregation function for each group (approx. 10k)

the groups are defined through known Y aggregation functions, weighted average of several samples:

- Y_Group1 = 0.5*Y_Sample1 + 0.2*Y_Sample2 + 0.3*Y_Sample3
- Y_Group2 = 0.8*Y_Sample4 + 0.2*Y_Sample5
- Y_Group3 = 1.0*Y_Sample6
- Y_Group4 = ...

where Y_GroupN is the Y value of group N

Each sample is including in only one group.

The basic solution would be to first aggregate X1,X2,...Xn at group level and then to perform the learning at this scale. But this is not correct as the weighted average is not applicable for some X variables.

I am wondering if a smarter method has been developed so far to perform the machine learning at sample level.

Optimally, I am looking for python scripts.

Thanks --

Comment: What you denote as Y(group) is a real-valued label, which you also denote as Y? and you want to learn a mapping from an arbitrary number of samples to Y?

Comment: (1) I replaced in the post Y(group) by Y_group. and mentioned that Y_group is the Y value of group N. 
(2) I want to learn a mapping from 10k Y values that could be related to 50k X1,X2,...Xn values using 10k known aggregation function.

Comment: OK, that's clearer, and one last question to make sure I understand. So you have about 10k groups, and 50k observations in total, so that on average you have 5 observations per group? And you have n features per observation/sample (i.e, what you denote as X1,X2,....,Xn is your feature vector of n dimension)? So your dataset is of size 50k times n.

Comment: Thanks Tom for taking some time to understand. Everything you said is correct. Some groups have more than 10 samples and some have just one. Average is around 5. The input dataset is 50k times n and the output one (Y variable) is 10k times 1

Comment: No worries. It seems like your problem falls in the world of multiple instance regression (MIR). Have a look at this paper, it could be useful: http://www.dabi.temple.edu/~vucetic/documents/wang12tgars.pdf. I have myself just submitted a paper to KDD 2019 about MIR problem. Let me know if that is what you are looking for

Comment: Yes - "multiple instance regression" is the appropriate term I was looking for. I need to dig more to see if such approach has been implemented with, for instance, a simple feedforward neural network.

Comment: If you look at the paper, you have 2 simple baselines (Instance-MIR and aggregated MIR). In my experience Instance MIR is the one yielding the best results out of the 2. You would simply fit a Feed forward network "independently" on all the samples and then average your predictions within each group, as the final prediction. Note that your NN needs to be fairly complex (read large hidden layer) in order to map different vectors to the same group label.

Comment: "You would simply fit a Feed forward network "independently" on all the samples and then average your predictions within each group, as the final prediction." - it is not exactly what I am looking for. I want to fit the same network for all sample but I am not able to perform the "fit"or the "learning" at sample level because I have Y observations only at Group level. I am still wondering how to account for the weighted average during the learning.